# Neo4J ogm testing create temporary database

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

i'm using spring and at the moment running my tests create new objects in my "real" embedded database. I want to create a new one or a temporary db just for testing. I'm new with spring and neo4j so could anyone please help?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the embedded driver with SDN/OGM you just need to configure it without providing a path. Then it will create embedded database in /tmp/.. which gets deleted on jvm exit.

E.g. if you are using java configuration

```
@Bean
public Configuration getConfiguration() {
   Configuration config = new Configuration();
   config
       .driverConfiguration()
       .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver");
   return config;
}
```

See docs for full documentation
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_configuring_the_embedded_driver

Comment: Thank you. I want to use my production and testing database at the same time. Now i know how to create a production and a testing database separate. You know what i mean?